# Handle font and image sizes =between iPhone 5, 6 and 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus, size-classes

Now that the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus has a lot more screen space i'm encountering a lot of screens in my app that are displayed "correctly" but has a lot of white spaces.

In this cases I want to make the fonts bigger, change the position of labels, and maybe even use bigger images to take more screen space (not @3 versions of the image but actual bigger size images).

What is the correct way to handle this - since Size Classes can only distinguish between iPhone and iPad devices?